# HTML when click submit http reset /?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make chat program. But when I click submit http is 
reset "localhost:3000/" to "localhost:3000/?"

Why http reset and append address ?

if i don't use server just run index.html also

file:///C:/Users/dude/Desktop/node/index.html?

this is index.html code

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title> chat with node js socket io </title>
 <style>
  #chat{
   height:500px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chat"></div>
 <form id="send-message">
   <input size="35" id="message"></input>
   <input type="submit"></input>
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't set any location in form tag. I suggest to use AJAX response.

Comment: You should explain what the expected behaviour is. In your given code the form has no named input elements so there is nothing to submit, the form has no `action` attribute as of that the current url is used and the default method is `GET`.  That's why you have your described behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to be a bit clearer on your information here.

Are you sure you want to submit the whole page? I think what you are looking for is not posting the information with the whole page, which is what the  form and submit will be doing.

If you use AJAX, you will only be sending the information you need, not the whole page, and update accordingly.

The "?" is part of the querystring, and should not affect the workings of your sofware. It is hinting that it is trying to do a "GET" with the form, which is the default behaviour. Do you have anything listening for the "GET" on the server?

I suggest to follow the standard HTML conventions in forms, by adding name attributes to your inputs, a URL where your form should be posting to ("action" attribute). Once you have standardized your HMTL, the next step would be to look at your functionality requirements. E.g. do you have your server functionality in place, where the chat info will be sent to?

Comment: I use {input method = "post" type="submit"></input} and Thank you answer!! it works